# how to set-up liveness and readiness probes for Celery worker pods

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, celery, self-healing

I want to set-up liveness and readiness probes for Celery worker pods.
Since these worker pods doesn't have a specific port associated to them I am finding it difficult.
Main Django app nginx server was easier to set-up.

I am very new to k8s so not much familiar to the different ways to do it.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4079) solution?

Answer (score 7):

liveness probe for celery worker:
This command only works when remote control is enabled.

```
$ celery inspect ping -d <worker_name> --timeout=<timeout_time>
```

When a celery worker uses a solo pool, healthcheck waits for the task to finish. In this case, you must increase the timeout waiting for a response.

so in yaml:

```
      livenessProbe:
        initialDelaySeconds: 45
        periodSeconds: 60
        timeoutSeconds: <timeout_time>
        exec:
          command:
          - "/bin/bash"
          - "-c"
          - "celery inspect ping -d <worker_name> | grep -q OK"
```

Of course you have to change the **worker name** and **timeout** to your own values

Comment: My question was about the set-up process through .yaml files.

Comment: u can add this command as https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command

Comment: This worked for me: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4079#issuecomment-1270085680

Answer (score 5):

Basically, configuration files in YAML for Celery liveness and readiness probes can be set up in a general way as described in Kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/). You can specifically adjust them for Celery pods based on your requirements, [for example](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4079#issuecomment-461413433):

```yaml
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            # bash is needed to replace the environment variable
            command: [
              "bash",
              "-c",
              "celery inspect ping -A apps -d celery@$HOSTNAME"
            ]
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 60  
          timeoutSeconds: 10
```

There is still ongoing GitHub issue on this matter - other solutions that might be useful for your set-up are described [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4079).